# Get list of parent sub-type with all sub-type in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, code-first

Using many Sub-Type tables with zero-one relation in C# code first!

```
 public class MemberContractRelation
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ContractId { get; set; }
    public long MemberId { get; set; }
    public long ListPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxCountryToPay { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxProvinceToPay { get; set; }
    public long InsuredCode { get; set; }

}


 public class FamilyMemberContractSubtype : MemberContractRelation
{
    public long CalculatedCheckupPrice { get; set; }

}
```

i want to getting list of my parent table (MemberContractRelation) with sub-type related record (like Left join) via this code :

```
 var familyMemberContractSubtype = _rep.FamilyMemberContractSubtype.Where(a => a.Id == ContractId).Select(x => new
          FamilyMemberInformationsBag
        {
            BirthDate = x.Member.BirthDate,
            FirstName = x.Member.FirstName,
            LastName = x.Member.LastName,
            NationalID = x.Member.NationalCode,
            PhoneNumber = x.Member.IranPhoneNumber,
            Price = x.ListPrice,
            ChekUpPrice = x.CalculatedCheckupPrice,
            TotalPrice = x.ListPrice + x.CalculatedCheckupPrice + x.TaxProvinceToPay + x.TaxCountryToPay,
            TaxProvinceToPay = x.TaxProvinceToPay,
            TaxCountryToPay = x.TaxCountryToPay

        }).ToList();
```

But it returns only records that have sub-Type and don`t return other records in MemberContractRelation! 
I want to get a list of MemberContractRelation with sub-type and if it has not recorded in sub-type return Null value of property in sub-type!

remember I cant use any other solution for my project except above solution!

Comment: This sounds like TPT EF inheritance pattern, is that correct?

Comment: yes something like that , but i dont know exactly about TPT details

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is using EF TPT inheritance strategy (as it seems), first you should start the query from the parent (base) table:

```
// instead of _rep.FamilyMemberContractSubtype
// assuming _rep is DbContext
_rep.Set<MemberContractRelation>()
```

and then use operator `as` (important: not cast!) to access subtypes members, promoting non nullable types to nullable. In your sample:

```
ChekUpPrice = (long?)(x as FamilyMemberContractSubtype).CalculatedCheckupPrice
```

and

```
TotalPrice = x.ListPrice + x.TaxProvinceToPay + x.TaxCountryToPay +
    ((long?)(x as FamilyMemberContractSubtype).CalculatedCheckupPrice ?? 0)
```